# Angular - Cannot change scope value after ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code in my template:

```
<div ng-if="selectedTheme.count_of_cards == 0" class="jumbotron" ng-controller="ThemesCtrl">
    <h1>{{ 'THERE_IS_NO_CARD' | translate }}</h1>
    <p>
        <a href="" ng-click="initEmptyTheme()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">{{ 'ADD_CARD' | translate }}</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**And called method on the ThemesCtrl:**

```
   $scope.initEmptyTheme = function() {
            //console.log("Trying to get cards for theme id: " +theme.id);
            //$rootScope.$emit('detailDisplayed', {});
            $scope.displayedTemplate = "default";
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.displayedTemplate = "default";
                    console.log("Meow");
                });
            });
        };
```

**EDIT:**

I also tried:

```
  $timeout(function() {
                $scope.displayedTemplate = "default";
                console.log("Meow");
            });
```

and

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.displayedTemplate = "default";
                    console.log("Maau");
                });
```

But nothing works.

I tried call the method with and without **timeout** and **apply** and console log is processed, but scope is not changed to "default" value (is still stucked on "empty" value).

What can be wrong please?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: remove your `$scope.$apply()`, since your using the `$timeout` service, call `$scope.$apply` causes and error and your code is not executing.

Comment: It is not working, i tried it before, see my updated question.

Comment: "It's not working": Is there an error in your console log, are you inspecting the scope with some tool or is the variable bound somewhere on the page and doesn't update?

Comment: variable is bound somewhere on the page and doesn't update

Comment: I found that it was caused by reinitialization of the controller in template. So it created the new scope.